# Using a temporary domain parking page as a permanent redirect page

Tags: domains

So, for obnoxious reasons there is no way for me to change the URL of my website. I can't switch hosts—the content needs to be stored where it is—so the best solution I could think of was to set up a redirect page from a website with another host that has my desired domain name with the URL www.example.com.

But I saw [this Go Daddy article about parking your domain name](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/338/parking-your-domain-name) and it says that when you park your domain name a temporary webpage is created. Could I park my domain name and turn this temporary webpage into a redirect to my pre-existing site?

If I can't do that, how do I setup a redirect to my existing page? Do I just need to do something like set up a google sites page, register my domain, change the google sites page URL, and then make the home page a [simple redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/how-to-redirect-from-an-html-page)? Is there any simpler process?

Comment: I have no experience purchasing or registering domain names, so I apologize if this question is in some ways confused. Any corrections or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Register your URL (domain name), then in your registrars domain settings, create a CNAME record pointing your new domain to your old domain.

Comment: @Kruug And that will accomplish everything I need? If so, feel free to convert to an answer and I'll accept and get this guy closed.

Comment: It should work, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointing a new URL to you old one is quite simple (this method is best used when you don't know the IP of your old URL, or it's a dynamic-based domain, such as DynDNS or a blogspot page).

First, register your domain/URL that you want to give out to people.  Then, in that domain's settings, create a CNAME record that points to the old domain.

Wait for the TTL to elapse and your domain should now be routable.